# Mongoose aggregate method does not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have these lines :

```
            Score.find({gameId : gameId}).exec(function(err,obj){
                console.log("find length : " + obj.length);
            });

            Score.aggregate([
                {$match: {gameId: gameId}}
            ], function (err, result) {
                console.log('result is : ' + JSON.stringify(result));
                console.log('is there any error : ' + err);
            });
```

And output of these lines are

```
result is : []
is there any error : null
find length : 1
```

I do not understand, why "match" method of aggregate does not work as expected - finding all documents, that match properties. I added `Score.find` with same "body" to find out, if the document really exist and it does.

PS : `{gameId: gameId}` - first gameId is name of property, second one is string value with ID I am looking for.

---

PS2: fluent api having same result :

```
            Score.aggregate().match({gameId: gameId}).exec(function (err, result){
                console.log('result is : ' + JSON.stringify(result));
                console.log('is there any error : ' + err);
            });
```

Comment: Have you also tried the fluent API methods `Score.aggregate().match({gameId: gameId}).exec(callback)`?

Comment: @chridam - tried now, same result

Comment: Have you tried convert it to mongoose id? `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(gameId)` or `new ObjectId(gameId)` for native

Comment: @styopdev - this is working `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(gameId)`, thanks! Write it please as answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should convert gameId string to mongodb ObjectId

in mongoose

`mongoose.Types.ObjectId(gameId)`

mongodb native way

`new ObjectId(gameId)`

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code :

```
Collection.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
    cid: ObjectId(req.params.cid),
    createdAt: {
      $gte: new Date(req.query.startDate),
      $lt: new Date(req.query.endDate)
    }
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      day: {$dayOfMonth: "$createdAt"},
      month: {$month: "$createdAt"},
      year: {$year: "$createdAt"}
    },
    count: {$sum: 1}
  }
}
]).then(function (result) {
  return res.json(result);
}, function (error) {
  return res.status(500).send(error);
});
```